# Executing finish() while there are pending Intent Services

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I launch one Intent Service.
Now i start another activity   ---> startActivity(this, blabla.class);
call finish()   ---> So, that the current activity cant be accessed from back button
Now the intents are being executed in the background. Will they be affected or is there anything else I need to be worried about?
Thanks

Comment: You mean, you start an external app or program via an Intent, and you won't get a return or reply? Then your Intent action is not affected by the finish().

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html),  services must be either stopped by themselfs, or explicitely by an event. Also, the system may at any point stop your service (usually for memory)

> A started service must manage its own lifecycle. That is, the system does not stop or destroy the service unless it must recover system memory and the service continues to run after onStartCommand() returns. So, the service must stop itself by calling stopSelf() or another component can stop it by calling stopService().

Comment: That is true of `Service`s in general, but OP is using `IntentService`. An `IntentService` manages its own lifecycle. It shuts itself down when it has nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Changing activities will not effect your [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).  It will do the necessary work and then shut itself down.

The only rare case where the system would shut it down is low memory situation.